# Error callback not working with Geolocation in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, geolocation

I've managed to successfully use the geolocation API in React Native, but when I turn my location off the error callback doesn't seem to work. I've tried providing a timeout option of 5 seconds and I could wait all day and the error would never be called. The weird thing is the error callback will be called if I turn the location back on. It will go to the error callback, then go back to the success.

I've tried using the following code:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (position) => {
    console.log("Got Position");
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log("Got error");
  }
);

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (position) => {
    console.log("Got Position");
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log("Got error");
  },
  {timeout: 5000}
);
```

I've also tried using the "react native android location services dialog box" module, but get the following error and just gave up:

```
android\app\src\main\java\com\orchardapp\MainApplication.java:7: error: package com.showlocationservicesdialogbox does not exist
import com.showlocationservicesdialogbox.LocationServicesDialogBoxPackage;
                                    ^
android\app\src\main\java\com\orchardapp\MainApplication.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
        new LocationServicesDialogBoxPackage(),
            ^
symbol: class LocationServicesDialogBoxPackage
2 errors
```

I'm building the app on an android 6 device. Just kind of stuck now and not sure what else to use... Has anyone experienced this and got some tips?

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't solved the problem yet, but I have found that the error callback will work if I create an app using the create-react-native-app module. I used the react-native init project method instead, but still not sure why the error callback won't work.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue seemed to be the version of React Native I was using. I updated it from 0.44 to 0.46 and the error magically worked. Most likely would have been because I was using an older version of the module, which could have been incompatible with some of the stuff I had in the code. :/

Anyway problem solved by updating!